# Test for parameter passed to NEST (elasticsearch)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, elasticsearch, nest

I am using NEST to do elasticsearch queries.

```
    public IReadOnlyCollection<IHit<Recommendation>> GetRecommendations(
        RecommenderQueryFields shoulds,
        RecommenderQueryFields musts, 
        RecommenderQueryFields mustNots)
    {
        var boolQuery = new BoolQuery();
        boolQuery.Should = GetQueryContainers(shoulds);
        boolQuery.Must = GetQueryContainers(musts);
        boolQuery.MustNot = GetQueryContainers(mustNots);

        var response = _elasticClient.Search<Recommendation>(s => s
            .AllTypes().From(0).Size(10)
            .Query(outerQuery => boolQuery));

        return response.Hits;
    }
```

I have logic in the `GetQueryContainers` method which I want to test. 
Is there some way to check what has been passed to the ElasticClient in the `boolQuery` object?

I have tried the following stuff already, using NUnit and NSubstitute.

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var searchResponse = Substitute.For<ISearchResponse<Recommendation>>();
        searchResponse.Hits.Returns(new List<IHit<Recommendation>>());
        var elasticClient = Substitute.For<IElasticClient>();

        var sut = new Recommender(elasticClient);

        // Act
        sut.GetRecommendations(null, null, null);

        // Assert
        elasticClient
            .Received(1)
            .Search(Arg.Is<Func<SearchDescriptor<Recommendation>, ISearchRequest>>(x => true));
    }
```

In the `Arg.Is<[...]>(x => true)` I would like to replace the `true` constant for some checks on `boolQuery`. But I do not know if it is possible or how it is done. Or is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use a derived `QueryVisitor`. See Edit2 below.

Found that the question has been answered already. It is not related to NEST, but to testing lambda expressions.
It is not possible: [C# Moq Unit Testing with Lambda Expression or Func delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40402456/c-sharp-moq-unit-testing-with-lambda-expression-or-func-delegate)

What can be done is testing the JSON request which will be sent to elasticsearch, but then you need the actual `ElasticClient`: [ElasticSearch NEST 5.6.1 Query for unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50814564/elasticsearch-nest-5-6-1-query-for-unit-test)

What can be done is putting the logic in its own method/class. But then you write code simply for the sake of testing, which I'm not a fan of. Like:

```
public BoolQuery GetBoolQuery(RecommenderQueryFields shoulds, RecommenderQueryFields musts,
    RecommenderQueryFields mustNots)
{
    var boolQuery = new BoolQuery();
    boolQuery.Should = GetQueryContainers(shoulds);
    boolQuery.Must = GetQueryContainers(musts);
    boolQuery.MustNot = GetQueryContainers(mustNots);
    return boolQuery;
}
```

You are exposing a `public` method which you are not intending for use, only for testing.
But you can then assert on `boolQuery` like this:

```
[Test]
public void GetRecommendations_CallsElasticSearch()
{
    // Arrange
    var elasticClient = Substitute.For<IElasticClient>();
    var sut = new Recommender(elasticClient);

    // Act
    var boolQuery = sut.GetBoolQuery(new RecommenderQueryFields{BlackListedFor = new List<string>{"asdf"}}, null, null);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1, boolQuery.Should.Count());
}
```

In `boolQuery.Should` is a list of `QueryContainer` which are not testable because it is generated with lambdas aswell. While better than nothing, it is still not a clean way to test NEST.

## Edit

@Russ Cam in the comment has mentioned the `IQueryContainer` and `QueryVisitor`
What I've got:

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    // Arrange
    var fieldValue = "asdf";
    var elasticClient = Substitute.For<IElasticClient>();
    var sut = new Recommender(elasticClient);

    // Act
    var boolQuery = sut.GetBoolQuery(new RecommenderQueryFields { BlackListedFor = new List<string> { fieldValue } }, null, null);

    // Assert
    IQueryContainer qc = boolQuery.Should.First(); // Cast to IQueryContainer
    Assert.AreEqual(fieldValue, qc.Match.Query); // Assert value

    // Get "field name"
    var queryVisitor = new QueryVisitor();
    var prettyVisitor = new DslPrettyPrintVisitor(new ConnectionSettings(new InMemoryConnection()));
    qc.Accept(queryVisitor);
    qc.Accept(prettyVisitor);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, queryVisitor.Depth);
    Assert.AreEqual(VisitorScope.Query, queryVisitor.Scope);
    Assert.AreEqual("query: match (field: blacklistedfor.keyword)\r\n", prettyVisitor.PrettyPrint);
}
```

The value of the field can be accessed via `IQueryContainer`.

I tried the `QueryVisitor` and the `DslPrettyPrintVisitor`. The first one doesn't provide any useful information. It has 0 depth and it is a Query? I already know that. With the second one I can assert some additional information, like the field name (blacklistedfor) and the suffix (keyword).
Not perfect to assert on the string representation, but better than nothing.

## Edit2

@Russ Cam gave me a solution which I am really happy with. It uses a derived `QueryVisitor`:

```
public class MatchQueryVisitor : QueryVisitor
{
    public string Field { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public override void Visit(IMatchQuery query)
    {
        var inferrer = new Inferrer(new ConnectionSettings(new InMemoryConnection()));
        Field = inferrer.Field(query.Field);
        Value = query.Query;
    }
}

[Test]
public void test()
{
    // Arrange
    var fieldValue = "asdf";
    var elasticClient = Substitute.For<IElasticClient>();
    var sut = new Recommender(elasticClient);

    // Act
    var boolQuery = sut.GetBoolQuery(new RecommenderQueryFields { BlackListedFor = new List<string> { fieldValue } }, null,
        null);

    // Assert
    IQueryContainer qc = boolQuery.Should.First();
    var queryVisitor = new MatchQueryVisitor();
    qc.Accept(queryVisitor);
    Assert.AreEqual(fieldValue, queryVisitor.Value);
    Assert.AreEqual("blacklistedfor.keyword", queryVisitor.Field);
}
```

So in `MatchQueryVisitor`, it gets the `Field` and `Value`, which are then asserted in the test method.

Comment: There is a `QueryVisitor` that can visit a `QueryContainer` and check it contains a query of a specified type. Another approach, if you know which queries to expect, is to cast to `IQueryContainer` and read the respective query property.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for pointing me to the `QueryVisitor` and `IQuerycontainer`. Updated my response.

Comment: You can derive a visitor from `QueryVisitor` and override any methods that you need to for your use case

Comment: You are my hero. I updated my response. I am happy with the code now.

Comment: @SimonLang this is great. Thank you for the detailed answer. Very helpful!!!